# Mi respuesta de objeto json me esta dando null, siendo que tengo una respuesta exitosa de "200"

Tags: android, get, retrofit, gson

Me falta la etapa final de mi aplicación, estoy usando Retrofit para un llamado **GET** dónde hay una respuesta objeto, pero me esta dando **NUll**, la verdad que no lo entiendo. hay algo seguramente que me este olvidando de aplicar.

dejo todas las capturas y código para que sirva de guía.

muchas gracias!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cómo verán mi respuesta es

**{
"CODIGO": 13,
"RAZON_SOCIAL": "CANON MEDICAL SYSTEMS"
}**

en mi app da el siguente resultado despues de correrlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi objeto clase es

```
public class _03011aDatareq {

@SerializedName("CODIGO")
@Expose
private Integer codigo;
@SerializedName("RAZON_SOCIAL")
@Expose
private String razonSocial;

public Integer getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Integer codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getRazonSocial() {
    return razonSocial;
}

public void setRazonSocial(String razonSocial) {
    this.razonSocial = razonSocial;
}
```

}

mi interface esla siguiente

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

@GET("jderest/v3/orchestrator/03_011B_ORCH")
Call <_03011aDatareq> getDatareqs(@Query("CUIT")String cuit,
                                        @Header("Authorization")String authHeader,
                                        @Header("Cookie") String cookie,
                                        @Header ("Content-Type") String content);}
```

mi main activity es

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textViewResult;
private TextView textoCodigo;

_03011aDatareq datareq1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textViewResult = findViewById(R.id.text_view_Resul);
    textoCodigo =findViewById(R.id.textPrueba);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://qcsys.servehttp.com:922/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();




    JsonPlaceHolderApi jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);

    String userName ="xxxxxx";
    String password ="xxxxxx";
    String base = userName + ":" + password;



    String authHeader = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(base.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    Call <_03011aDatareq> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.getDatareqs("30716002361", authHeader,"JSESSIONID=fYAV2KfouyICoHiKGuJ5n_-Q0kQOc-KNl6HmFk9Ce8K5JQtuMa7A!-530853743", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");



    call.enqueue(new Callback<_03011aDatareq>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<_03011aDatareq> call, Response<_03011aDatareq> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful())  {
                textoCodigo.setText("code: "+ response.code());


                _03011aDatareq modal = response.body();

                textViewResult.setText("Codigo: " + modal.getCodigo()+ "\n" + "Razon social: " + modal.getRazonSocial());
                

            }
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<_03011aDatareq> call, Throwable t) {
            textoCodigo.setText(t.getMessage());
            }



        });


    }

}
```

He debuggeado la clase objeto de la respuesta y me da el siguiente texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo es posible que me de "Null" si esta dando una conexión exitosa de código "200"

Comment: Yo trataría de hacer debug del contenido del response ANTES de asignarle el body al modal, pues no es evidente que estés deserializando correctamente :)

Comment: Revisa la salida del LogCat, debe haber sin duda un problema de serialización cuando se intenta mapear la respuesta a la clase y allí debe decirte exactamente cuál es el problema y dónde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución!

mi Objeto Clase estaba asi

**private Integer codigo;**

pero es un int "codigo", entonces lo reemplacé

**private int codigo;**

despues de modificar eso, el resultado que esperaba fue exitosa, gracias a los comentarios pude avanzar. muchas gracias!